# formatting Json string

Tags: php, json

I have a sql table quiz(level,data,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer); php code

```
$link=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sencha_db',$link);
$query="Select * from quiz where level='$Level'";
$res=mysql_query($query);   
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    $q[]=$row[2];
    $op1[]=$row[3];
    $op2[]=$row[4];
    $ans[]=$row[5];

}    
$response = array('success' =>'res',
                   'level'=>$Level, 
                   'q1'=>$q,
                   'op1'=>$op1,
                   'op2'=>$op2,
                   'ans'=>$ans
                 );

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

how can i able to get json strings like (is it possible to get multiple string)

```
{'level':'somedata','question':'question1','option1':'option1data','option2':'option2data','answer':'answer1'}
{'level':'somedata','question':'question1','option1':'option1data','option2':'option2data','answer':'answer1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want an array of objects:

```
$response = array();

$query="Select level, question, option1, option2, answer from quiz where level='$Level'";
$res=mysql_query($query); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $response[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Yes, you can have as many `echo`s as you want, but the resulting output should be JSON as well. What you posted is not valid JSON.